# What am I doing wrong with the CSV part of my code

Tags: python, csv, user-input

So, in my python code I'm supposed to  prompt the user for their name, address, and phone number and write that data as a line of comma separated values to the file using the directory and filename. Everything runs except the CSV part.

```
import os
import csv

def file_system():
    """Display information about users"""
    direc = input("Enter name directory to save a file: ")
    filename = input("Enter name of the file they want to save to the directory: ") 
    name = input("Enter your name : ")
    address = input("Enter your address : ")
    phone_number = input("Enter your phone number : ")
    print  (direc, filename, name, address, phone_number)

    prompt = input()



    if os.path.isdir(direc):
        writeFile = open(os.path.join(direc,filename),'w') 
        writeFile.write (direc, + filename)
        writeFile.close() 
        
        print("File contents:")


        readFile = open(os.path.join(direc,filename),'r') 
        for line in readFile:
            print(line)

        readFile.close()
    if prompt:
       with open('Userdata.csv', 'a',
              newline='') as outfile:
          
          w = csv.writer(outfile)
          w.writerow(name, address, phone_number)
           
          print("File Updated")
         
    

    else:
        print("Directory doesn't exist, please enter again")

file_system()
```

Comment: The CSV part of my code still isn't running. The rest runs. But the part I asked about I'm still stuck.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the evaluation of the `if` statement before the csv section.

run the code below twice, first time just pressing enter, second time typing something and then pressing enter...

```py
prompt = input("input something:\n")

if prompt:
    print("you got here")
else:
    print("you didn't")
```

As you can see, when only pressing enter, the `if` statement becomes `False`...